# Sql one foreign key for different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys

First of all, I do realize that there are plenty of questions regarding this problem and there is a good chance that I already know one of the answers, but after I've tried a couple of them, none of them worked for me.

In my application I am handling communication between user and customer. Both users and customers can have multiple e-mail addresses. Also, both users and customers can be assigned to multiple conversations at the same time. After user or customer sends an e-mail message, system receives information about that and creates a ConversationMessage with basic info about the message and EmailMessage with specific data (subject, FROM, TO etc.).

[image: Database schema]

Right now, fields FROM and TO are just varchar fields with e-mail addresses. I would like to change it so that FROM and TO fields are foreign keys. I was planning to create an EmailAddresses table that would store basic info about the address and UserEmailAddresses and ContactPersonEmailAddresses tables with specific info about address (like host, port etc.), but I realized that EmailAddresses table would contain just an Id. Is it a good approach? Am I missing something?

Are there any better solutions to this kind of problem?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Presumably the EmailAddresses table would have the email address in addition to the ID right? There is nothing wrong with that approach at all. But do you need to have that level of normalization? Do you anticipate having multiple users having the same email address? Sometimes this makes sense but it sounds like it is very likely over normalization.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with Sean but then again I work with databases that people share email addresses and they have more than 1.  But I would think of things like this.  A person is a person is a person and an email address is an email address.  meaning no need for separate email tables for users and persons.  So your users table reference person already no need to carry first and last a second time it will just give you a headache to keep in sync you can create views/functions to get to it.  In addition to the email table you then need a person to email cross ref table

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you for response. EmailAddresses table could indeed have an address field, I forgot about that. I cannot see the normalization issue though. One user can have multiple email addresses, but one address can be assigned to only one user ([User] field in UserEmailAddresses table).

Comment: Honestly I didn't look closely at your posted schema before my response. I don't think this is a case of over normalization. As I did say in my first comment, assuming you need this normalization (which looks like it would be a good design here) there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your approach.

Comment: @Matt Thank you for response. I don't know if I got it right, but do you suggest that I create a single "EmailAddress" table that would only reference "Persons" table and EmailMessages table would reference EmailAddress in FROM and TO fields? If I create that table, should it contain all fields (like port, host etc.) and then in case of customer's email address should these fields be left null?

Comment: Yes one email table referenced by 2 foreign key constraints in EmailMessages (for FROM and TO).  But also a PersonEmailCrossRef table which holds the relationships between Person and Emails you can add constraints to enforce only 1 person having an email address etc.  As far as Where to put ports, host, etc I am not sure exactly what you are trying to track but if you want all of the email details then that would be in EmailMessages or its own table because Ports, hosts, etc. can change perhaps not frequently but they do.  Also they are more than likely related to domain not email

Comment: Storing port etc. might be overkill too you may want to just store the headers in the EmailMessages table it would take up more space but make more since when load balancing etc is in play.  as for as Customers email addresses why would you leave that null.  A customer is a Person so if your Customer has a foreign key to Person and Person has a key to the PersonEmailCrossRef then by traversing the keys your customer can have email addresses as well....  This is why I am suggesting a person is a person is a person (a user, customer, contact) etc. are all people

Comment: do the relationships on the base class (table)  Person to Email to Email Message etc.  Going from your inherited classes User/Customer over complicates and makes things redundant.

Comment: @Matt Ports and hosts are IMAP server data and each user's email address has that data stored so system is able to connect to imap server to get incoming messages etc. I am not storing that data for customer's email addresses. Thank you for helping me realize that some of those tables are unnecessary and showing me your approach.

Comment: oh I got it you want to store authentication data to be able to get to the IMAP email then I would store that on the Email table or perhaps a domain table for the port and server address and password on email table (encrypted of course :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerable issues with the design but let's limit the discussion to the email addresses. You store the addresses in two tables. This, unsurprisingly, is causing problems.

An email address is an entity. Store them in a table. Anywhere a single address is needed, place a FK to the one address table there. Where multiple addresses is or may be needed, place an intersection table there.

```
create table EmailAddresses(
  ID     int   auto_generating primary key,
  Addr   varchar not null unique,
  Active bool
);
```

Are such fields as Login, Port, etc. really attributes of an email address? Maybe you could clarify those if you would.

Then the tables UserEmailAddresses and ContactEmailAddresses would be intersection tables and look something like this:

```
create table [User|Contact]EmailAddresses(
  UserID   int  not null references [Users|Contacts]( ID )],
  AddrID   int  not null references EmailAddresses( ID )
);
```

As an email message can only have one "From" value, that would be in the EmailMessages row as it is now except it can now be a FK to the one address table. A message may have one or many "To" values so that would be implemented also as an intersection table:

```
create table EmailTo(
  EmailID  int  not null references EmailMessages( ID )],
  ToID     int  not null references EmailAddresses( ID ),
  ToType   enum( To, CC, BCC )
);
```

There are probably other requirements that would require some constraints on any or all of the tables above but those depend on your usage. For example, even though email applications allow the same address to exist more than once in a From list, you may want to catch and restrict such occurrences. This would be implemented by a unique constraint on (EmailID, ToID)

Possible extensions would be the addition of email lists which themselves contain a group of addresses. That would require the EmailAddresses table to split but because all addresses are now located in one table, such a redesign would certainly be easier that having them located in two tables.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Login, Port etc are fields used for connecting to user's Email (IMAP) server. This way system has access (while user is logged in) to incoming messages etc. I already solved the issue by removing separate Email tables and creating one table that references Persons table. Thank you for the multiple To fields idea though, I didn't really think about it and it's a very good idea.